# HTML: Adding <STYLE> and <SCRIPT> tags via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, dom

If a JavaScript function in a web page adds `STYLE` or `SCRIPT` elements to the `HEAD` element, will the browser load the specified styles and scripts, or will such programmatic changes to the DOM ignored after the page has been loaded?

Is the behavior consist across all mainstream browsers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can add scripts and stylesheets via JavaScript, and they will work.  Google Analytics does this, for example.

Comment: +1 with additional: if script elements are inserted using `innerHTML`, they are not likely to be executed consistently across all browsers.  They must be constructed using the proper DOM creation method, `document.createElement()`.

Comment: The good old `document.write('<script src="...">');` is still popular.

Comment: document.write() can't be used reliably after the page has already loaded.